# Refresh entire Excel workbook (all data connections and calculations) every 15 minutes?

Tags: excel, vba, refresh

I have the following macro to refresh my workbook. This is the same as clicking on the refresh all button.

Is there a time element I can add to this code to refresh all **data connections** and all **calculations** on **all the worksheets** in my workbook every 15 minutes?

The workbook has cells pulling data from SharePoint list items and contain typical formula calculations as well.

```
Sub Workbook_RefreshAll()
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter the following in a standard module:

```
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalMinutes = 15
Public Const cRunWhat = "Workbook_RefreshAll"

Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, cRunIntervalMinutes, 0)
    Application.OnTime earliesttime:=RunWhen, procedure:=cRunWhat, _
         schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.OnTime earliesttime:=RunWhen, _
       procedure:=cRunWhat, schedule:=False
End Sub

Sub Workbook_RefreshAll()
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Call StartTimer
End Sub
```

To begin the process run `StartTimer()` and to end the process run `StopTimer()`

Adapted from [Chip Pearson's Site](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/OnTime.aspx)

I used some Shapes to run the macros:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gary. Am I looking to put the StartTimer() and StopTimer() into their own individual modules? This is would be a great route to take especially given that I can just create a start and stop button for the workbook.

Comment: @user1266515  When I tested the code I just posted, I put all the code in a single standard module and assigned `StartTimer()` and StopTimer()` to some Shapes on the worksheet.

Comment: That's interesting. I wasn't aware of the fact that functions within a single module could be called through buttons or shapes.Thanks again!

Comment: @user1266515  **Just right-click the Shape and assign the macro!**

Comment: Yup got it!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Application.OnTime` method to schedule a macro to be run in the future: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx

Yet, this is a one time event only. To make it recursive, you'll have to include in that macro (yet again) another `Application.OnTime` to ensure a calling "every 15 minutes".

Answer (score 0):

to refresh all calculations you can use:

```
application.Calculate
```

P.S.: Sorry my english