# makro to refresh excel file (all connections) between two times (between 6:00 and 8:00 am)

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file

Hi everybody here is the story:

I'm working with an excel file that pulls data from various PowerPivot connections and it takes about 15 min to refresh. I wrote a simple makro that refresehs the file and saves it. Then I tried to trigger it via a batch file. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with excel markos and batch files so I only managed to open the excel file via the batch file. Hence I'm looking for a makro that automatically refreshes (and saves) the excel file when it's opened but only between 6:00 and 8:00 am. Now I can trigger the batch file to open the excel file at 7:00 and when I get to work I can open the refreshed excel file without having to wait for 15 mins until it's refreshed.

Thanks a lot Phil

p.s.
The question is very similar to:
[Macro to refresh an entire excel workbook(all data connections and calculations) every 15 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867158/macro-to-refresh-an-entire-excel-workbookall-data-connections-and-calculations/39846786#39846786)
but I need to have some adjustments to it

Comment: You'll need an if statement, in the Workbook_Open, so if time>timeserial(6,0,0) then UpdateWorkbook() something like that.  No need for a scheduled approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sub Launcher()
    application.ontime 42647.42 , "refresher" 'time of refresh
    'you may make a loop to set several ontime, one every 15min, I'm too lazy for that
end sub
sub refresher()
    calculate
    thisworkbook.save
end sub
```

EDITED: maybe you're thinking of this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    if now-int(now) > 6/24 and  now-int(now)  <8/24 then refresher
end sub
```

Comment: I don't think there is need for the ontime, as op says between 6 and 8, so I think workbook open, checking time, then calling refresher if time is >6 and <8

Comment: yep I haven't drunk my coffee yet ( 10AM here) and thought he wanted to launch at specific hours. :-)  I'll edit my answer

Comment: 9am here, and I spotted it :)

Comment: I'm no morning guy... too much text, I couldn't read properly all... XD

Comment: Thank you very much the Edited version + refresher is doing the job, thanks!