# Clearing Excel AutoFilter using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this VBA code to refresh my entire workbook at specific time intervals. ([thanks to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867158/macro-to-refresh-an-entire-excel-workbookall-data-connections-and-calculations))

As you can see, it is currently set to refresh every 60 minutes.

```
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalMinutes = 60
Public Const cRunWhat = "Workbook_RefreshAll"

Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, cRunIntervalMinutes, 0)
    Application.OnTime earliesttime:=RunWhen, procedure:=cRunWhat, _
         schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.OnTime earliesttime:=RunWhen, _
       procedure:=cRunWhat, schedule:=False
End Sub

Sub Workbook_RefreshAll()
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Call StartTimer
End Sub
```

The code works great, however there’s one thing I wish it could also do:

1. Any time the sheet is opened, and/or
2. Any time this VBA code executes the sheet refresh process

I would like the AutoFilter to be "Cleared" (not disabled or turned off) as in the screen grab below:

[AutoFilter Clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7zzk.jpg)

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Cheers

Comment: What you mean by `Any time the sheet is opened` ? When a sheet changes? or? Also point 2 is even less clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. You may of course do it for one Sheet only, if you wish.

```
Sub Workbook_RefreshAll()
Dim sh As Worksheet
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not (sh.AutoFilter Is Nothing) Then sh.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Next sh
    Call StartTimer
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Wolfgang.  Can you please let me know where this code goes in relationship to my existing VBA.  For example, does it belong above, below or in a separate module?  Thanks.  One last question if you don't mind:  rather than just clearing the AutoFilter entirely, is there any way for the AutoFilter to be cleared and then reinstated back to whatever setting it set for.  Or, is it only possible to clear the AutoSetting filter entirely.  Thanks again very much for your prompt and generous support.  Cheers

Comment: Wolfgang -- please ignore the post directly above.  I got nailed with a timeout while editing it.  Here is what it should have said:   -------- Thank you very much Wolfgang.  Can you please let me know where this code goes in relationship to my existing VBA.  For example, does it belong above, below or in a separate module?  Thanks.  One last question if you don't mind:  how would this code change if I only wanted to "Reapply" the AutoFilter -- rather than clearing the AutoFilter?  Thanks again very much for your prompt and generous support.  Cheers

Comment: 1st: My `Workbook_RefreshAll()` would replace your `Workbook_RefreshAll()`. As you can see, I just made some insertions.

Comment: 2nd: Use `If Not (sh.AutoFilter Is Nothing) Then sh.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter` instead of `If Not (sh.AutoFilter Is Nothing) Then sh.AutoFilter.ShowAllData` to re-apply the current filter.

Comment: Thanks very much Wolfgang.  I will test.  I really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Thanks again Wolfgang. Marked as Answer.